# How to fix changing fontawesomefx icons to a rectangle when the font size is specified in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx, font-awesome

I'm using fontawesomefx-8.9 and I have set their font size to 15px using

```
.glyph-icon {
  -fx-font-size: 15px;
}
```

Then I have created some FontAwesomeIconViews and embed them in some Buttons(JavaFX).

The issue I had to face is changing fontAwesome icons to a rectangle when hovering mouse over the button.

[image]

FXML File is below(FXMLDocument,fxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" stylesheets="@styles.css" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="test_fontawesome.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="41.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
         <graphic>
            <FontAwesomeIconView fill="BLUE" glyphName="CUT" />
         </graphic></Button>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Button fx:id="button1" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="41.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
         <graphic>
            <FontAwesomeIconView fill="BLUE" glyphName="PLUS" />
         </graphic>
      </Button>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

CSS is file below(styles.css)

```
.root {
    -fx-font-size: 12px ;
}
```

Just preview it on scene builder, the issue will appear!

If you want the source code, get it from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B84k1fZRHSMdNTdwVTlDWm1XQmM).

Comment: Are you sure the button displays the same glyph when hovered over? This looks like a character issue, not a size issue. Check the CSS for `:hover`.

Comment: Yes I am! I did not modified any css hover events in the default modena.css I have edited my question by adding my fxml and css files. Just preview it on scene builder after linking fontawesomefx-8.9.jar to the scene builder. I also included sample netbeans project having this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i had the same issue sometime back ..  i remember adding the following line to my css file fixed the issue.

```
.glyph-icon{ -fx-font-family:"Material Design Icons"; }
```

Looks like your are using FontAwesome icon , may be try with the appropriate font family for that.

```
  .glyph-icon{ -fx-font-family:"FontAwesome"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider to switch to the latest version of FontAwesomeFX.
Yesterday I released 8.14: http://www.jensd.de/wordpress/?p=2579
8.14 comes with a fix of these resizing issues!

Comment: Glad to see you, Thanks!

Comment: can anbody tell me how to download above file from http://www.jensd.de/wordpress/?p=2579

Comment: Nice, It's working! But it still causes the same bug if we added inline css as -fx-font-size: 12px;

Answer (score 0):

If you change the font-size, you must set the font-family for icon.

```
.glyph-icon {
  -fx-font-size: 15px;
  -fx-font-family: "FontAwesome"; /* or Material Design Icons*/
}
```

This fix my issue! ;)