# FontAwesomeIconView Shows Icon in SceneBuilder, Fails in Application

Tags: java, javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder, glyphicons

I am using FontAwesomeFX in my project and added a `FontAwesomeIconView` inside a button with glyph name property set to `WINDOW_MINIMIZE`. This part can be seen as XML as below.

```
<Button fx:id="minimizeButton" mnemonicParsing="false">
   <graphic>
      <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="WINDOW_MINIMIZE" />
   </graphic>
</Button>
```

The problem is, it shows up successfully in SceneBuilder as seen below:

[image: FontAwesomeIconView WINDOW_MINIMIZE]

However, when I boot up the program, I see these in debug logs:

```
Dec 21, 2017 11:49:50 PM de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon updateIcon
SEVERE: Icon 'WINDOW_MINIMIZE' not found. Using 'ANCHOR' (default) instead
```

And the application shows `ANCHOR` instead of `WINDOW_MINIMIZE`.

[image: FontAwesomeIconView Anchor icon]

I have also applied this CSS rule due to sizing problems with `FontAwesomeIconView`s [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967590/2926992) (just in case it is related to the problem):

```
.glyph-icon{ -fx-font-family:"FontAwesome"; }
```

#### Why Different Imports in SceneBuilder and Maven

As you can see in **Environment** section below, I imported different thing in my Maven configuration file and SceneBuilder.

Well, the reason is, oddly, SceneBuilder does not see `FontAwesomeIconView` when you import `de.jensd:fontawesomefx:8.9`, that's why I imported `de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2` in SceneBuilder and it works well with Maven import.

So, why didn't I do the other way? I mean, why didn't I import `de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2` in my `pom.xml`. Strangely, it is compiled in Java 9 and my project is running on Java 8. Naturally, it threw class version exception or something like that. Also, I didn't have any idea if the migration to Java 9 would cause more trouble, so I didn't import it in `pom.xml`.

---

## Environment

- Java 1.8.0_151
- JavaFX 8.0.151 build 12
- SceneBuilder 9.0.1
- de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-9.1.2 (Scenebuilder)
- [GroupID] de.jensd [ArtifactID] fontawesomefx [Version] 8.9 (in `pom.xml`)

Comment: If you project runs on Java 8, maybe you should use Scene Builder 8.4.1, and FontAwesomeFX 8.15?

Comment: will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I dig through a bit and saw that, oddly, `FontAwesomeIcon` enum in `de.jensd:fontawesomefx:8.9` (which is the latest version in Maven Central Repository) does not contain any `WINDOW_MINIMIZE` icon.

That's why, I changed my icon to something else that is in `FontAwesomeIcon`. That solved my issue for now, yet this question is still open for further answers.

Comment: Did you see this at the project's [repo](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) `Since FontAwesomeFX 8.10 I moved to Bintray, so you have to add the bintray repo to you build file as it is not yet available at Maven Central!`. You have new releases [here](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/view).

Comment: Whoa, I seem to not recognize it, let me try it. I will add further details to this answer. Thanks.